# Chat search is broken

Tags: bug, chat

I know you SO people don't care about chat at all. Nor do you care about fixing chat search, however I don't think you meant to really break it this time.

Whatever I try to search it doesn't give any results, e.g.:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo&user=&room=11

results in:

> 0 messages found

I'm fairly certain it is really a bug this time and not a result of tweaking the search functionality.

Comment: You do know all stuff moved to Denver? Could be related...

Comment: Related tweet: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/630026367434924032

Comment: Nope wasn't aware of that. /me puts the wheel of blame away again

Comment: It is a network-wide issue, the other chat domains give the same result. On the plus-side: search performance has improved dramatically....

Comment: [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263342/searching-on-chat-always-returns-no-results)